# Avoid network access for local files with Uri content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content

Tags: android, android-image, android-contentresolver

I have an app that allows the user to pick images from the device. When the images are picked from the Google Photo app, the Uri that I get is something like:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2<id>
```

When I use the following code to create a bitmap with this Uri, it seems like I am hitting the network and the image is being downloaded.

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

However, when I switch my phone to airplane mode and try to access the same image or any other image, I get:

```
content://media/external/images/media/17239
```

So it seems like these images are available on the local device. Is there anyway to avoid network access when the device has connectivity, if the image is available locally?

Comment: You can find answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-can-i-open-an-html-file-i-have-copied-from-pc-to-sd-card-of-phone)

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji: This link doesn't seem to answer my questions. Can you please point me to the place where it answers it? I am basically concerned that the input stream would be pointing to the external URL, not sure if there is some internal magic to point it to the local image.